# Regex for # and text between # and trailing whitespace

Tags: jquery, regex, regular-language

I am trying to get regex for:

- Get "#" and all text between "#" and trail ending "\t"(whitespace).

So far I have:

```
/#[a-zA-Z0-9]\t/
```

This seems wrong? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by whitespace you mean actual whitespace (that is spaces, tabs, etc), then this does it:

```
/#\S+/
```

<sup>(`\S` is equivalent to `[^\s]`)</sup>

If you however meant `tabs`, when you wrote whitespace, then this:

```
/#[^\t]+/
```

Comment: '\S' is for whitespaces? and whats the '+' do? I still need to get everything between the two is well.

Comment: No, `\s` is for whitespace, `\S` is for **all but** whitespace. And the `+` means one times or more. So, in short the regex says: "look for a # followed by one or more characters that is/are not whitespace/tabs (depending on the regex above)." And obviously it will stop collecting once it encounters a character that does not match the criteria (criteria here: not a whitespace/tab character).